# ProtoInclude in abstract class - dlls cannot know about each other

Tags: c#, interface, include, protobuf-net

we have the following scenario:

an abstract class in dll1

a class that inherits from it, in dll2.

dll2 references dll1. (so we cannot reference the child class - cyclic dependency)

how can we `ProtoInclude` the child class? the type would be unknown.

Please provide sample documentation for runtimemodel, if that's the only way.

Comment: Why would the abstract class need to know about the child class?

Comment: the mechanism we have serializes for the consumers. we want it to remain a general solution. meaning, the action shouldn't happen from the child class (only protobuf definitions).

Comment: hi ChrisBD: because protobuf doesn't have the notion of inheritance, and the way to solve it is "teaching" the parent about the possible children.

Comment: @ChrisBD for the same reason that it would in XmlSerializer (`XmlInclude`) or DataContractSerializer (`KnownType`)

Comment: ChrisBD: thanks for your willingness to help :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

1. use the *string* version of the assembly-qualified-name, instead of `typeof()` - sounds brittle, but is actually how much of the .NET BCL hangs together (see typical BCL usage of: `EditorAttribute`, `TypeConverterAttribute` etc)

   ```
   [ProtoInclude("Full.Namespace.Type, Assembly, ...")]
   ```

   (it should also work for just the type+assembly, but fully versioned may help too)
2. do the binding at runtime (only available in v2) in your app code that spans both assemblies:

   ```
   RuntimeTypeModel.Default[typeof(BaseType)].AddSubType(13, typeof(SubType));
   ```

Comment: ah, I think I see, so the RuntimeTypeModel is static?

Comment: @better-than-soil no; you can have as many parallel models (with different rules) as you like; `.Default` is the default instance, that `Serializer.Serialize<T>` etc uses. A `TypeModel` is thread-safe and is intended to be used lots of times (don't create one per usage)

Comment: hi Marc, thanks for everything. 
We now try version2 with the code sample you suggested, however there is a conflict with CodeContracts. Have you ever encountered this problem?

Comment: CodeContractRewrite:
  "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Contracts\Bin\ccrewrite" "@xxx.Globalsccrewrite.rsp"
  Reading assembly 'xxx.Globals' from 'D:\....xxx.dll' resulted in errors.
   Could not resolve type reference: [protobuf-net]ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel.
   Could not resolve member reference: ProtoBuf.Meta.RuntimeTypeModel::get_Default.
ccrewrite : error : Rewrite aborted due to metadata errors. Check output window

Comment: @better-than-soil is it possible that something somewhere is still referencing v1, and the code-contracts re-writer is choosing the wrong reference?

Comment: yeah, my bad. i renamed the file to protobuf-net2.dll. once I renamed it back (without the 2, it compiled)